# Secondary Namenode not starting

Tags: java, hadoop

I am getting this error after setting up hadoop version 1.0.3:

$bin/start-all.sh

```
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

starting namenode, logging to /var/log/hadoop/daley/hadoop-daley-namenode-datapath3.cise.ufl.edu.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /var/log/hadoop/daley/hadoop-daley-datanode-datapath3.cise.ufl.edu.out
localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /var/log/hadoop/daley/hadoop-daley-secondarynamenode-datapath3.cise.ufl.edu.out
localhost: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: file:///
localhost:  at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:162)
localhost:  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:198)
localhost:  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:228)
localhost:  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getServiceAddress(NameNode.java:222)
localhost:  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.initialize(SecondaryNameNode.java:161    )
localhost:  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.<init>(SecondaryNameNode.java:129)
localhost:  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.main(SecondaryNameNode.java:567)
starting jobtracker, logging to /var/log/hadoop/daley/hadoop-daley-jobtracker-datapath3.cise.ufl.edu.out
localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /var/log/hadoop/daley/hadoop-daley-tasktracker-datapath3.cise.ufl.edu.out
```

The only solution i am getting from google is to set fs.default.name which I have set as
   hdfs://localhost:9100

Answer (score 0):

From the error information you provided, the problem may be that the port of the secondary namenode has been occupied, probably by another hadoop system on the same machine. So setting the configuration fs.default.name  is a good way. Another way is to kill the proccess which occupy the port, which may cause another service crash.